# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list error with xml file reading

Tags: python, xml, list, tags, dataset

I have xml file that I want read and extract images annotation from, following is a snapshot of one of the files:

```
 -<annotation>
<folder>VOC2007</folder>
<filename>000021.jpg</filename>
-<source>
<database>The VOC2007 Database</database>
<annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>
<image>flickr</image>
<flickrid>326914724</flickrid>
</source>
-<owner>
<flickrid>Apple Crisp</flickrid>
<name>Layne Russell</name>
</owner>
-<size>
<width>336</width>
<height>500</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
-<object>
<name>dog</name>
<pose>Right</pose>
<truncated>1</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>1</xmin>
<ymin>235</ymin>
<xmax>182</xmax>
<ymax>388</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
-<object>
<name>person</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>210</xmin>
<ymin>36</ymin>
<xmax>336</xmax>
<ymax>482</ymax>
</bndbox>
-<part>
<name>head</name>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>238</xmin>
<ymin>37</ymin>
<xmax>287</xmax>
<ymax>104</ymax>
</bndbox>
</part>
-<part>
<name>foot</name>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>220</xmin>
<ymin>411</ymin>
<xmax>278</xmax>
<ymax>444</ymax>
</bndbox>
</part>
</object>
```

I am trying to remove the part tag with all the information because its confusing, this is the code I am trying to use:

for img, ann in zip(imgpath, AnnPath):

```
sample_image = Image.open(img)
# sample_image.show()
with open(ann) as annot_file:
    print(''.join(annot_file.readlines()))
tree = ET.parse(ann)
root = tree.getroot()

    for neighbor in root.iter('object'):
    className=str(neighbor.find('name').text)
    print(className)

    for neighbor2 in neighbor.iter('part'):
        for neighbor3 in neighbor2.iter('bndbox'):
            xminN = neighbor3.find('xmin')
            yminN = neighbor3.find('ymin')
            xmaxN = neighbor3.find('xmax')
            ymaxN = neighbor3.find('ymax')

            root.remove(xminN)
            root.remove(yminN)
            root.remove(xmaxN)
            root.remove(ymaxN)
```

but I am getting the error:

> root.remove(xminN)

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Please post all `import` lines so we know what modules you use. Also, your XML appears cut off with no root.

Comment: `root.remove(xminN)` cannot work because `xmin` is not a direct child of the root element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to remove the tags using `decompose()` method.

This code removes all the `<part>` tags from the XML.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''
 <annotation>
<folder>VOC2007</folder>
<filename>000021.jpg</filename>
<source>
<database>The VOC2007 Database</database>
<annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>
<image>flickr</image>
<flickrid>326914724</flickrid>
</source>
<owner>
<flickrid>Apple Crisp</flickrid>
<name>Layne Russell</name>
</owner>
<size>
<width>336</width>
<height>500</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
<name>dog</name>
<pose>Right</pose>
<truncated>1</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>1</xmin>
<ymin>235</ymin>
<xmax>182</xmax>
<ymax>388</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
<object>
<name>person</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>210</xmin>
<ymin>36</ymin>
<xmax>336</xmax>
<ymax>482</ymax>
</bndbox>
<part>
<name>head</name>
<bndbox>
<xmin>238</xmin>
<ymin>37</ymin>
<xmax>287</xmax>
<ymax>104</ymax>
</bndbox>
</part>
<part>
<name>foot</name>
<bndbox>
<xmin>220</xmin>
<ymin>411</ymin>
<xmax>278</xmax>
<ymax>444</ymax>
</bndbox>
</part>
</object>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
v = soup.find_all('part')
for i in v:
    i.decompose()
                
print(soup)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<annotation>
<folder>VOC2007</folder>
<filename>000021.jpg</filename>
<source>
<database>The VOC2007 Database</database>
<annotation>PASCAL VOC2007</annotation>
<image>flickr</image>
<flickrid>326914724</flickrid>
</source>
<owner>
<flickrid>Apple Crisp</flickrid>
<name>Layne Russell</name>
</owner>
<size>
<width>336</width>
<height>500</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
<name>dog</name>
<pose>Right</pose>
<truncated>1</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>1</xmin>
<ymin>235</ymin>
<xmax>182</xmax>
<ymax>388</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
<object>
<name>person</name>
<pose>Unspecified</pose>
<truncated>0</truncated>
<difficult>0</difficult>
<bndbox>
<xmin>210</xmin>
<ymin>36</ymin>
<xmax>336</xmax>
<ymax>482</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: Really sorry it's my mistake I am trying to remove "part" tag not object, I edited the question, not sure why the code can not find the part tag. knowing that the "part" tag is inside the 'object' tag

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. please check